# Convert HoughLinesP output line format to HoughLines output line format

Tags: opencv, houghlinesp

### Reminder

**HoughLines** output lines:

[image]

**HoughLinesP** output lines:
[image]

### Question

how to move from HoughLinesP lines format to HoughLines lines format ?

**Details**
I've made an algorithm based on the HoughLines output lines, so I dont really need segments ending points information.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple geometry. You need to pass from a line defined by two points `(x1, y1), (x2, y2)` to the polar equation `(rho, theta)`.

You can find the formula to compute `rho` from two points [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points) (where `(x0, y0)` = (0, 0)). 
And the formula to compute theta [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope). Note that you need to compute the angle of the line *perpendicular* to the one defined by your points.

You can find the code in the function `twoPoints2Polar` below in this small testing code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

cv::Vec2f twoPoints2Polar(const cv::Vec4i& line)
{
    // Get points from the vector
    cv::Point2f p1(line[0], line[1]);
    cv::Point2f p2(line[2], line[3]);

    // Compute 'rho' and 'theta'
    float rho = abs(p2.x*p1.y - p2.y*p1.x) / cv::norm(p2 - p1);
    float theta = -atan2((p2.x - p1.x) , (p2.y - p1.y));

    // You can have a negative distance from the center 
    // when the angle is negative
    if (theta < 0) {
        rho = -rho;
    }

    return cv::Vec2f(rho, theta);
}


int main()
{
    cv::Mat3b img(300, 300, cv::Vec3b(0,0));

    // x1, y1, x2, y3
    cv::Vec4i u(50, 130, 250, 80);

    // Get rho, theta
    cv::Vec2f v = twoPoints2Polar(u);

    // Draw u in blue
    cv::line(img, cv::Point(u[0], u[1]), cv::Point(u[2], u[3]), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);

    // Draw v in red
    float rho = v[0];
    float theta = v[1];
    double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
    double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
    cv::Point pt1(  cvRound(x0 + 1000 * (-b)),
                    cvRound(y0 + 1000 * (a)));
    cv::Point pt2(  cvRound(x0 - 1000 * (-b)),
                    cvRound(y0 - 1000 * (a)));
    cv::line(img, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, 8);

    cv::imshow("Lines", img);
    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is old, but is the 1000 param there arbitrary ? For me it puts the lines outside of the original image. What I wanted the detected lines to correspond to the lines in the image ? Like an overlay. Is there a way to constrain the line to the image ? Where can I learn more about this ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can not receive the same line from this function
input 
[2825 1213 2900 1823]
polar
-2655.8617490041315 -0.12233683381549594
converted back to x, y
(-1415, 10249, -3856, -9601)
Problem is in if "(theta < 0) "